# How to debug the android app from eclipse to samsung galaxy pop?

Tags: android

I'm using Samsung galaxy pop. I want to debug the application from eclipse to device. This will be working fine to my HTC mobile. But whenever I was connected the samsung android device, it's not connected to my eclipse.

How to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

1. Download Kies on your pc after it enable debugging mode in mobile setting

go in setting->applcation->development->enable usbdebugging.

Answer (score 1):

First of all have you checked that your USB Drivers for your Samsung are installed? You can find an introduction over [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) and driver for Samsung over [here](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads).

Furthermore, you need to set your phone for USB-Debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Update your device driver
then download Samsung kies for your phone and then enable usb debugging in your phone
then select target in eclipse as manual and you are ready to go..